# Rails4 Error: rake aborted! Don't know how to build task 'doc/app/index.html' (see --tasks)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database-migration

```
$ rake db:migrate
```

or

```
$ bundle exec rake db:migrate
```

i am getting error like

```
rake aborted!  
Don't know how to build task 'doc/app/index.html' (see --tasks)
```

Comment: Surely there's more to your stack trace. Your log should show the file and line number where the error occurs.

Comment: Run `$ rake db:migrate --trace` and and investigate what went wrong. If you can't find the answer edit your question with the full trace. May be someone will be able to help.

Comment: Thanx @MarsAtomic , @Dhrubo_moy           i just created _doc/app/index.html_ (empty file) that error fixed but now I am getting error :: _NoMethodError: undefined method `source_index' for Gem:Module /home/akriti/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/rails-2.3.18/lib/rails/gem_dependency.rb:21:in `add_frozen_gem_path'_

Comment: What's the exact version of both Rails and Ruby you're using?